# Parsing a document with BeautifulSoup while not-parsing the contents of <code> tags

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup, pygments

I'm writing a blog app with Django. I want to enable comment writers to use some tags (like `<strong>`, `a`, et cetera) but disable all others.

In addition, I want to let them put code in <code> tags, and have pygments parse them.

For example, someone might write this comment:

```
I like this article, but the third code example <em>could have been simpler</em>:

<code lang="c">
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
</code>
```

Problem is, when I parse the comment with BeautifulSoup to strip disallowed HTML tags, it also parses the insides of the <code> blocks, and treats <stdbool.h> and <stdio.h> as if they were HTML tags.

How could I tell BeautifulSoup not to parse the <code> blocks? Maybe there are other HTML parsers better for this job?

Comment: See my reference below. That deals with the same problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<code>` is treated according to the normal rules for HTML markup, and content inside `<code>` tags is still HTML (The tags exists mainly to drive CSS formatting, not to change the parsing rules).

What you are trying to do is create a different markup language that is very similar, but not identical, to HTML. The simple solution would be to assume certain rules, such as, "`<code>` and `</code>` must appear on a line by themselves," and do some pre-processing yourself.

1. A very simple — though not 100% reliable — technique is to replace `^<code>$` with `<code><![CDATA[` and `^</code>$` with `]]></code>`. It isn't completely reliable, because if the code block contains `]]>`, things will go horribly wrong.
2. A safer option is to replace dangerous characters inside code blocks (`<`, `>` and `&` probably suffice) with their equivalent character entity references (`&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`). You can do this by passing each block of code you identify to `cgi.escape(code_block)`.

Once you've completed preprocessing, submit the result to BeautifulSoup as usual.

Comment: Option #2 seems like a winner. How would I go about that? Regular expressions, or some sophisticated string processing algorithm?

Comment: @Dor: I've amended my answer to cover this.

Comment: I've tried this, but obviously cgi.escape expects a string, not a BeautifulSoup tag object :) How can I escape the contents of the tag prior to the parsing?

Comment: You should extract the text between the `<code>` and `</code>` lines as per my original answer, pass it through `cgi.escape` and concatenate it all back together. Then (and only then) pass the whole thing to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Marcelo Cantos: [_That's the main part of the question - *how?* – @Dor Oct 24 '10 at 15:47_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007434/parsing-a-document-with-beautifulsoup-while-not-parsing-the-contents-of-code-ta/4007459#4007459)

Answer (score 1):

From [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml)

```
>>>import cgi
>>>cgi.escape("<string.h>")
>>>'&lt;string.h&gt;'

>>>BeautifulSoup('&lt;string.h&gt;', 
...               convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

Comment: That way I'd have to write every possible tag, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Dor: why? just pass everything inside `<code>` to `cgi.escape`

Comment: That's the main part of the question - how?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, BeautifulSoup can not be blocked to parse the code blocks.**

One solution to what you want to achieve is too

1) Remove the code blocks

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(content))
code_blocks = soup.findAll(u'code')
for block in code_blocks:
    block.replaceWith(u'<code class="removed"></code>')
```

2) Do the usual parsing to strip the non-allowed tags.

3) Re-insert the code blocks and re-generate the html.

```
stripped_code = stripped_soup.findAll(u"code", u"removed")
# re-insert pygment formatted code
```

I would have answered with some code, but I recently read a blog that does this elegantly.

- http://iboris.com/page/add-source-code-syntax-highlighting-your-django-content-pygments.html

Comment: When I first parse the string, BeautifulSoup inserts the closing </stdbool.h> and </stdio.h> tags. So even if I used this technique I'd still get these closing tags in my code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

Use [python-markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) to process the input, and have users indent the code areas.

```
>>> print html
I like this article, but the third code example <em>could have been simpler</em>:

    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

>>> import markdown2
>>> marked = markdown2.markdown(html)
>>> marked
u'<p>I like this article, but the third code example <em>could have been simpler</em>:</p>\n\n<pre><code>#include &lt;stdbool.h&gt;\n#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;\n\nint main()\n{\n    printf("Hello World\\n");\n}\n</code></pre>\n'
>>> print marked
<p>I like this article, but the third code example <em>could have been simpler</em>:</p>

<pre><code>#include &lt;stdbool.h&gt;
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
</code></pre>
```

If you still need to navigate and edit it with BeautifulSoup, do the stuff below.
Include the entity conversion if you need the '<' and '>' to be reinserted (instead of '<' and '>').

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(marked, 
                     convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
>>> soup
<p>I like this article, but the third code example <em>could have been simpler</em>:</p>
<pre><code>#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
</code></pre>


def thickened(soup):
    """
    <code>
    blah blah <entity> blah
        blah
    </code>
    """
    codez = soup.findAll('code') # get the code tags
    for code in codez:
        # take all the contents inside of the code tags and convert
        # them into a single string
        escape_me = ''.join([k.__str__() for k in code.contents])
        escaped = cgi.escape(escape_me) # escape them with cgi
        code.replaceWith('<code>%s</code>' % escaped) # replace Tag objects with escaped string
    return soup
```

Comment: It creates artifacts such as `</stdbool.h>` and `</stdio.h>`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you're absolutely right, it was working for me, and I just realized the difference--I had passed it through markdown. Rewriting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `<code>` element contains unescaped `<`,`&`, `>` characters inside the code than it is not a valid html. `BeautifulSoup` will try to convert it to a valid html. It is probably not what you want.

To convert the text to a valid html you could adapt [a regex that strips tags from an html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840763/trouble-getting-regular-expression-to-work/4841189#4841189) to extract the text from a `<code>` block and replace it with `cgi.escape()` version. It should work fine if there is no nested `<code>` tags. After that you could feed sanitized html to `BeautifulSoup`.